# Access to the project classes from library project C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, oop, c#-6.0

I have the following question.

I am currently working on a C # project and need to create some library projects, but at the time of creating these projects I was presented with the following scenario:
I need access to the classes in the main project from within the library projects
Since my data base access layer is in the main project, I'm looking for a way so that I don't have to add this into every library project.

Really only needed to execute SELECT statements. I use ADO.NET to execute all transactions over the data base.

Any help will be really useful.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Listen to uncle @Habib. don't even try to do what you do. Although, it is totally possible. An exe in .net can be referenced same way as dll and if you have public API - there you go. But this is just bad idea

Answer (score 4):

It is not a good idea to reference the executable/main project in the library project. It should be vice versa.

The Library project should be independent of the application's platform. What you should do is to extract the data access code in another library project. That way you will be able to access it in other libraries/projects.